# Showing codimension of subspace of C[0,1] equals 1

Tags: vector-spaces, banach-spaces

> Show that $\overline{\{f∈C^1[0,1]:f(0)=0\}}$ as a subspace of $C[0,1]$ has codimension 1.

Attempt: define $T:C[0,1]\to$ $\Bbb{R}$ by $T(f)=f(0)$. 
$T$ is a surjective continuous linear transfomation between Banach spaces.
 
Thus $C[0,1]/\{f∈C[0,1]:f(0)=0\}\cong\Bbb{R}$ and $\mathrm{codim}(\{f∈C[0,1]:f(0)=0\})=1$. 
As $\overline{\{f∈C^1[0,1]:f(0)=0\}}\subseteq\{f∈C[0,1]:f(0)=0\}$
 it follows that $\mathrm{codim}\overline{\{f∈C^1[0,1]:f(0)=0\}}\ge$$1$
 
I don't know how to show the other direction of the inequality.
Thank you.

Comment: In your fourth line, how did you come up with that? In general, it is always true the other way around: $\;A\subset \overline A\;$ . You did the contention the other way.

Comment: this isn't the same spaces. The left side related to C^1[0,1] and the right to C[0,1]

Comment: Didn't notice that, thank you. But why did you do that? Why did you pass to work with $\;\mathcal C[0,1]\;$ instead of the original $\;\mathcal C^1[0,1]\;$ ?

Comment: because I know the codimsndion(=1) of the space when I work with C[0,1].

Comment: It is always the same: on any non-trivial linear space,  any non-zero linear functional's kernel is a maximal subspace and thus its codimension is one.

Comment: Do you mean that I should define $T$:$C^1[0,1]$$\to$R ? but then, as $C^1[0,1]$ is not complete as a subspace of $C[0,1]$ I'm not sure that I can say that Range(T) isomorphic to the quotient space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36111/discussion-between-user313122-and-joanpemo).

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I've shown that $\ker(T)=\overline{\{f∈C^1[0,1]:f(0)=0\}}$. 
By Weierstrass approximation theorem I've a polynomial function $p_{1}$ s.t. $||f-p_{1}||<\mathcal{E}/2$.
Let $p(x)=p_{1}(x)-p_{1}(0)$. Then $p\in\overline{\{f∈C^1[0,1]:f(0)=0\}}$ and $||f-p||<\mathcal{E}$ as desired.